# Jest-dynamoDB connection gets refused inside of docker container

Tags: docker, testing, amazon-dynamodb, jestjs, amazon-dynamodb-local

I have a suite of tests written in Jest for dynamoDB that use the dynamodb-local instance as explained [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/dynamodb) using [this dependency](https://github.com/shelfio/jest-dynamodb). I use a custom-built Docker image which builds a container within which the tests are executed.
Here's the Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

RUN apk -v --no-cache add \
    curl \
    build-base \
    groff \
    jq \
    less \
    py-pip \
    python openssl \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    yarn \
    && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip awscli boto3 aws-sam-cli

EXPOSE 8000
```

I `yarn install` all of my dependencies and then `yarn test`, at this point after a long time it will output this:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgkbS.png)

This is the command I ma using:
`docker run -it --rm -p 8000:8000 -v $(pwd):/data -w /data aws-cli-java8-v15:latest`

The tests work completely fine on my own machine, but no matter what project I use or what I include in my Dockerfile connection always gets dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, turns out it has to do with Alpine Linux. Because it uses musl instead of Glibc local dynamodb won't be able to start and it will crash a few seconds after it was executed without outputting any error messages. The solution is to either use OracleJDK on alpine, which is hard enough given their new license or using any other OS that does use glibc with OpenJDK. Or you could try to install glibc on Alpine and try to link it to your OpenJDK, but it's not a terribly good idea.